# OpenCart - Show a single attribute instead of all

Tags: php, opencart

I need to show a single attribute out of many attributes on product page. For example, I have author, publisher and format attributes for a product; and want to show only author in product page. Following code is showing all attributes in tabular format:

```
<?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
    <div>
      <?php echo "<strong>",$attribute['name'], ":\n</strong>"; ?>
      <?php echo $attribute['text']; ?>
</div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Better way to show single attribute for a product is to go to your product edit panel and remove all the attributes except the one you want to show

[image]

If you still want to do it in code **which is not recommended** then you can use and if your desired attribute

```
    <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) {
    if($attribute['name']=="Clockspeed") { 
     /* your attribute name for e.g i have used Clockspeed */
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Showing "Undefined variable: attribute_group" error ... where to define attribute group, means in my case attribute group is "Bibliographic" and attribute name is "Format".

Comment: @user2985872 Replace **Clockspeed** with **Format**

Comment: @user2985872 if above answer solves your problem then read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)